Prometheus Solr Exporter
I'm trying to monitor a solr using  promethus exporter
./bin/solr-exporter -p 9309 -b http://localhost:8309/solr -f ./conf/solr-exporter-config.xml
it was working fine until enable the basic authentcation
now throw
ERROR - 2024-06-10 10:39:22.691; org.apache.solr.prometheus.collector.SchedulerMetricsCollector; Error occurred during metrics collection => org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseHttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8309/solr: null

org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseHttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8309/solr: null

request: GET
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.Http2SolrClient.processErrorsAndResponse(Http2SolrClient.java:839) ~[solr-solrj-9.1.0.jar:9.1.0 aa4f3d98ab19c201e7f3c74cd14c99174148616d - ishan - 2022-11-11 13:00:47]
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.Http2SolrClient.processErrorsAndResponse(Http2SolrClient.java:500) ~[solr-solrj-9.1.0.jar:9.1.0 aa4f3d98ab19c201e7f3c74cd14c99174148616d - ishan - 2022-11-11 13:00:47]
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.Http2SolrClient.request(Http2SolrClient.java:459) ~[solr-solrj-9.1.0.jar:9.1.0 aa4f3d98ab19c201e7f3c74cd14c99174148616d - ishan - 2022-11-11 13:00:47]
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.request(SolrClient.java:1193) ~[solr-solrj-9.1.0.jar:9.1.0 aa4f3d98ab19c201e7f3c74cd14c99174148616d - ishan - 2022-11-11 13:00:47]
        at org.apache.solr.prometheus.scraper.SolrStandaloneScraper.getCores(SolrStandaloneScraper.java:90) ~[solr-prometheus-exporter-9.1.0.jar:9.1.0 aa4f3d98ab19c201e7f3c74cd14c99174148616d - ishan - 2022-11-11 13:00:47]
        at org.apache.solr.prometheus.scraper.SolrStandaloneScraper.pingAllCores(SolrStandaloneScraper.java:49) ~[solr-prometheus-exporter-9.1.0.jar:9.1.0 aa4f3d98ab19c201e7f3c74cd14c99174148616d - ishan - 2022-11-11 13:00:47]
        at org.apache.solr.prometheus.collector.PingCollector.collect(PingCollector.java:42) ~[solr-prometheus-exporter-9.1.0.jar:9.1.0 aa4f3d98ab19c201e7f3c74cd14c99174148616d - ishan - 2022-11-11 13:00:47]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:271) ~[solr-solrj-9.1.0.jar:9.1.0 aa4f3d98ab19c201e7f3c74cd14c99174148616d - ishan - 2022-11-11 13:00:47]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840) ~[?:?]


now try to connect to solr after enable the basic authentcation

Have you customized solr port ? You can haven't mentioned about standalone mode or cluster mode. Sharing document reference. Hope it helps.
$ cd prometheus-exporter 
$ ./bin/solr-exporter -p 9854 \
  -b http://localhost:8983/solr \
  -f ./conf/solr-exporter-config.xml \
  -n 8

Solr documentation reference
